# How to show an index page of apps with Meteor.js on IOS and Android

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-ios

We want to use Meteor.js to make an app which will show an index page which will link to several apps on the iphone/android. If one of the apps isn't installed we would like to show it slightly greyed out and then prompt the user to install it if they click that particular link.

Is this possible with Meteor.js? And if so... what are the modules I need to install to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a kinda broad question, I'll try to cover the main tasks you have to perform:

1. **Find out what apps are installed:**
   There are several Cordova plugins to do this, f.e. [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appavailability). Googling or searching SO should provide some more, although most of them only support Android, so watch out for that. Some can also get icons of installed apps, if that's important to you. So you will have to install the Cordova plugin of choice.
2. **Display them:**
   Show the list of (un)installed apps to the user. Meteor can definitly help you here. F.e. you could create some list template like described in the [documentation](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/templates). Of course other frameworks could do the same... So you might want to install meteor or another framework.
3. **Prompt to install an uninstalled app:**
   I think providing a link to the app in the PlayStore/iTunes is a good idea here. Again something to do in meteor or the GUI framework of choice. Nothing else needed here ;)